# Web scraping with PowerShell - an empty href

Tags: powershell, web-scraping

I am trying to get download links from web pages, but in some web pages some of `<a>` tags look like this: `<a href="#" ...`.

For example, this page
https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/thankyou.html?standalone=1&system=true&platform=win
has a link with "click here to retry" inner text, which looks like
https://dl.google.com/tag/s/appguid%3D%7B8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96%7D%26iid%3D%7B3218A264-6918-BBE2-56B1-1CEFAB4A9C43%7D%26lang%3Den%26browser%3D3%26usagestats%3D0%26appname%3DGoogle%2520Chrome%26needsadmin%3Dtrue%26installdataindex%3Ddefaultbrowser/update2/installers/ChromeStandaloneSetup.exe
in any web-browser, but not in PowerShell.

### What doesn't work

I tried `Invoke-WebRequest`:

```
PS> $url="https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/thankyou.html?standalone=1&system=true&platform=win"  
PS> (Invoke-WebRequest $url).Links | ? {$_.InnerText -eq "click here to retry"} | select outerHTML, href | fl

outerHTML : <A class=retry-link href="#" data-g-label="retry-dl"
            data-g-event="retry-download">click here to retry</A>
href      : #
```

Other methods - `System.Net.WebClient`, `System.Net.WebRequest + StreamReader` - return the same result. I guess it's because they don't process javascripts in web pages, but correct me if I wrong.

### Works

Using IE works, all right. But it's SO SLOW and... feels like an overkill. This code does the job:

```
$url="https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/thankyou.html?standalone=1&system=true&platform=win"

$ie = New-Object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.silent  = $true

$ie.Navigate2($url)
while ($ie.busy)                               { Start-Sleep -m 100 }
while ($ie.Document.readyState -ne 'Complete') { Start-Sleep -m 100 }

$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | ? { $_.InnerText -eq "click here to retry" } | select -First 1 -expandProperty href
Write-Host $link
```

### Any alternatives?

If you know how to get a proper `href` values from such links without using IE, please let me know.

Comment: There are two ways to get what you want.  Either have a browser run the javascript, or find and parse the script file yourself to extract the URL.

Comment: @Ryan Bemrose  
> or find and parse the script file yourself to extract the URL.  

And how do I do that? Write my own universal javascript parser? (You not serious, right?)

Comment: Obviously parsing the JS isn't feasible for the all sites, but it might make sense if you only want to parse one site (eg: the Google Chrome download page)